# Selenium webdriver.Firefox() not working on windows

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape images from the web using selenium. On Linux there do not seem to be any problems however when running on windows the program seems to exit on line 18.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import requests
import base64


def webscrape(query, max_count, q):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    # Add a GH_token to the environment so there are no limitations on the number of requests.
    os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = "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"
    gecko = GeckoDriverManager().install()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(gecko), options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "&tbm=isch")
print("test")
```

the test print doesn't happen. But all print statements before the `driver.get` call do.

Comment: paste the code into the question. Do not post screen of the code

Comment: how to ask a question properly:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example